# Is there any default editor in ubuntu image

Tags: kubernetes

Now the kubernetes DNS could not resolve. I want to edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` to remove the default DNS server IP, but there is no editor tool in the image, and I could not download one from the internet.

There is any default tool that could edit the file? (`vim`/`vi` does not exist).

Comment: What image are you using? Where did you get it? Did you try `nano`?

Comment: I find cat tool could edit@terdon

Comment: If you are talking abpir DNS resolution in Kubernetes-hosted containers, I doubt that the solution is editing the DNS in the container. since the container can be destroyed and recreated from the initial image. But your problem is most likely in the K8S config.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best option editing the `/etc/resolv.conf` inside a container. Pods are ephemeral, and you will lose this configuration on container restart.

You need to use the [`dnsConfig`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-dns-config) configuration, and define `nameservers` values:

> Pod's DNS Config allows users more control on the DNS settings for a Pod.
>
> `nameservers`: a list of IP addresses that will be used as DNS servers for the Pod. There can be at most 3 IP addresses specified.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: dns-example
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: nginx
  dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 8.8.4.4
```